# Quarto Book HTML output changed font after updating quarto version

Tags: quarto

I have an issue since I updated my Quarto to the 1.3.450 using the official build from their website. I am using a Quarto book with an HTML output and a cosmo theme. After updating, my book changed with a smaller and different font in the entire document (ToC, text, headings, etc.).

I am not sure where to look at, I have tried changing the theme and switching back to cosmo, but even if I use 'default' for instance, the font seems to be changed.

Has anyone experienced the same and can help me fix it?

Thank you in advance so much!

[image: Old "correct" font]

[image: New weird font]